# SQL using a transaction to swap two numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to swap two phone numbers for two employees in a database using a transaction. I am not sure I am understanding variables in SQL as I keep getting an error. Am I referencing these variables wrong for the swap? Here is what I have so far:

```
use lunches;

start transaction;

set @phone1 = (select phone_number
from l_employees
where employee_id = '205');

set @phone2 = (select phone_number
from l_employees
where employee_id = '209');

update l_employees
set phone1 = @phone2, phone2 = @phone1;
```

I am getting an error that there is an unkown column 'phone1' in field list. How do I get the values in the two variables I created to swap?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what happens when you update them as 2 statements?

Comment: Gnerally you have to declare vaiables before you can set their values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for multiple statements or variables, this can be done in a single statement:

```
update emp
  set phone_number = case 
                       when 205 then (select phone_number from emp where employee_id = 209) 
                       when 209 then (select phone_number from emp where employee_id = 205) 
                     end
where employee_id in (205, 209);
```

This is also safe for concurrent updates because the first statement to be executed will lock the two rows that are being updated. And it's atomic because it's a single statement.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your `SELECT` it looks like your `UPDATE` queries should be:

```
update l_employees
set phone_number = @phone2
where employee_id = '205'

update l_employees
set phone_number = @phone1
where employee_id = '209'
```

Why are you using a transaction?  Are you expecting either phone number to change in the middle of the operation?  Seems unlikely for 4 queries that should be very fast.

Comment: It is a best practice to use a tracnaction anytime you have more than one action query not matter how fast you think they may run. This would be left in a  bad state if one record got changed and not the other.